# Wordpress: Error in get post by met_key

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

I have this code,

```
    $type = get_the_ID();
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $units3 = new wp_query( array(  'post_type' => 'units' ,
                                    'posts_per_page'=> 6 ,
                                    'paged' => $paged  ,
                                    'meta_key' => 'unittype',
                                    'meta_value' => $type ) ); 
    while ($units3->have_posts()) : $units3->the_post();
```

Its must get me all post from `unit` That is in the unit type that `id = $type` 
But the query is get me all post.

It must get me only all post from unit post type that in unit type post type,

Where is error

Comment: Have you tried to use `get_posts()` or `new WP_Query` instead of `new wp_query`. I think you have a writing issue here.
More information on http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts or http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query.
Also are you sure get_the_ID() Method is right for your $type variable

Comment: Nice:) but how can check if have post or not ??

Comment: you could write `var_dump( $units3 );` so you can see if your query returns any posts. By the way, `new wp_query` doesn't exist in Wordpress.

Comment: Ok, but can i check more than meta_key, i need to get all post tha in unit type and has sale :), So i need to use 2 meta_key

Comment: Should be possible. Look at https://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-for-multiple-meta-keys-and-values

Answer (score 0):

Meta key is for using meta_value_num in order parameter,

You need to use meta_query for querying specific meta data

Test your query first until you get the correct data

```
$data = query_posts( array(
                'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',  
                'meta_key' => 'your_order_meta_key', 
                'posts_per_page'=> 5,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'key_to_only_display_if_exist',
                        'value'   => array( 3, 4 ),
                        'compare' => 'IN',
                        )
                    )
                ) 
            ); 
var_dump($data);
```

Then Use query_post

```
query_posts( array(
                'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',  
                'meta_key' => 'your_order_meta_key', 
                'posts_per_page'=> 5,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'key_to_only_display_if_exist',
                        'value'   => array( 3, 4 ),
                        'compare' => 'IN',
                        )
                    )
                ) 
            ); 
      if (have_posts()) :
          while (have_posts()) : the_post();
              echo '<div class="post-entry">';
              echo '<h2><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2>';
              echo '<div class="entry-content">'. apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content('Read More')).'</div>';
              echo '</div>';
          endwhile;
      endif;
wp_reset_query();
```